# How to create a table with reserved keyword column name in vertica?

Tags: sql, database, vertica, reserved-words

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer
(
    user int NOT NULL
);
```

This gives syntax error.

It works when using double quotes but then in the column name double quotes also appear in the table.

Comment: Using double quotes is the only way to do that. But I highly recommend to simply find a different name for that column.

Comment: Use a different name!  Just say "NO" to using reserved words -- or even unreserved keywords -- as identifiers.  In this case, the name should probably be `userId` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query against Vertica:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE reserved='R'
```

You should avoid using any of the returned keywords in that query for any object you want to create in the database - you will end up having to put double quotes around the name all the time otherwise.

That's practically SQL standard